# Progressbar during folder copy

Tags: c#, copy, directory

I need to display progress while folders are copying (asynchronous).
I'm able to do that with a single file copy, but not with a folder... I just want to display the progress of the overall copy as Windows does.

Here is my code for copying folder:

```
private void DirectoryCopy(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);

    DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();
    // If the destination directory doesn't exist, create it.
    if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
    }

    if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
    {
        throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
            "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: "
            + sourceDirName);
    }

    // Get the files in the directory and copy them to the new location.
    FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
        string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);
        file.CopyTo(temppath, false);
    }

    // If copying subdirectories, copy them and their contents to new location.
    if (copySubDirs)
    {
        foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
        {
            string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);
            DirectoryCopy(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs, cts.Token);
        }
    }
}
```

Then this is called through a button :

```
await Task.Run(() => DirectoryCopy(
    srcFolder, 
    @"\\" + hostname + @"\C$\" + destFolder + @"\", 
    true, 
    cts.Token
));
```

How can I achieve this?

Tell me if there is not enough information about my issue, I will update my post.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please show us *what you have tried so far* and/or *what error do you get?*

Comment: what are you using - WPF / WinForms or Console app ?

Comment: custom solution for copying multiple files, this link may help to understand basics : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36647/How-to-copy-files-in-C-with-a-customizable-progres

Comment: Sorry, i'm using WPF. Thank's for your link, but it doesn't apply to my needs :(

Answer (score 3):

You could make use of IProgress interface.

For example,

```
private async Task DirectoryCopy(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs, CancellationToken cancellationToken,IProgress<int> progress)
{
    // Do work
    var percentageProgress = 0;
    // percentageProgress = Calculate percentage
    progress.Report(percentageProgress);
}
```

And at the client (believe your button click event),

```
var progressIndicator = new Progress<int>(ShowProgress);
await UploadPicturesAsync(sourceDirName,destDirName,copySubDirs,token,progressIndicator);
```

Where ShowProgress is defined as

```
void ShowProgress(int value)
{
// Update UI
}
```

You can read more on IProgress [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/) and [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html) too

Comment: Thank's for this example. Can I ask you something ? Considering my code above, how can I calculate the percentage ? By the way, I guess it's the solution I need :)

Comment: @Rems May be I would be do it non-recursively. Recursive makes it harder to "measure" progress. A non-recursive approach using "SearchOption.AllDirectories" might be a better option.